Receiving and using cookies in typescript / javascript / html
So I'm trying to use token for account authentication, so I receive the token from the backend using cookie-parser, like this:
const token = await ViewToken(AccEmail, AccPassword);
res.statusCode = 200;
res.cookie("authToken", token, {httpOnly: false,}).send();

And I receive it successfully in my Login page and after it confirms the login, it redirects the user to another html page but when I try to use the token cookie from the first page it isnt there! How do I use cookies received in one html page in another separate html page?
I'm using this to fetch the cookie:
const resToken = await fetch("http://100.93.233.91:3000/GetToken", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: h,
    credentials: "include"
});
if(resLogin.ok && resToken.ok){
    const token = await resToken.json();
    localStorage.setItem("authtoken", token);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("authtoken"));
    window.location.href = "MainPage.html";
}

but when I console.log(localStorage.getItem("authtoken")); it appears as void.
Receiving a cookie in one page and accessing it's content in another page

Why not just send the token in the response body? No reason to deal with sending it is a cookie if you're not using it as a cookie

I needed help with that, because how can i use a cookie between two html pages, the localstorage was just a test that i made but didnt work

Ask about that issue instead then. https://xyproblem.info/
